# Gradle Application Plugin: Run CLI application without Gradle output and delays

Tags: java, gradle, command-line-interface

I am developing a command-line application and am using the Gradle Application Plugin to run it. My application contains a simple `print`/`readline` loop. Upon running it with Gradle, I get a `<==========---> 80% EXECUTING` line put by Gradle in between my application's output lines.

If I run my application like this: `TERM=dumb ./gradlew run` the in-between output is gone, however I am facing a delay of around 500ms between my `readline` and the next `print`. Is there any way how I can configure Gradle to run my application without its own logic around it?

Comment: What happens when you try `./gradlew run --console=plain --quiet`?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by [Slaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6395627/slaw)'s comment, the solution is to run

```
./gradlew run --console=plain --quiet
```